# Equivalent replacement for ListProperty(db.Key) in djangoappengine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-models, django-nonrel, djangoappengine

I and trying to use [djangoappengine](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine), but I am unsure how can I write model to incorporate standard

```
ListProperty(db.Key)
```

I know that djangotoolbox provides this field types but I am unable to figure out the exact syntax.

Comment: Is this the correct way : 
cities = ListField(models.ForeignKey(City))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

db.ListProperty(db.Key) stores a list of any entity's keys.

models:

```
class Profile(db.Model):
data_list=db.ListProperty(db.Key)

class Data(db.Model):
name=db.StringProperty()
```

views:

```
prof=Profile()
data=Data.all()

for data in data:
    prof.data_list.append(data)

/// Here data_list stores the keys of Data entity

Data.get(prof.data_list) will get all the Data entities whose key are in the data_list attribute
```